# Jackson Modules not being registered in all Spring Boot ObjectMapper instances?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application where my Jackson modules are being registered, like jdk8, jsr-310 and money. The objectmapper used by actuator endpoints uses the same objectmapper and the modules are registered, but when I call my defined WebMVC @RestController endpoints, a different objectmapper instance is used with no defined modules registered. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: how have you setup Spring MVC in your Spring Boot application. Looks like you have put `@EnableWebMvc` in your application removing the auto configuration for that part.

Comment: Yes. I have another project using spring boot 1.5.2 and it works but this one is using spring boot 1.5.3. I am trying to get my other project to revert to 1.5.2 to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: How is that an answer to my comment?  If you have `@EnableWebMvc` you loose the configured `ObjectMapper` for Spring MVC.

Comment: I have tried it with and without. But, let me verify again.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. I found that annotation on my imported exception handling class. Thanks. Removing it solves my issues.

Comment: But, I have to question why this causes my issue when the spring boot documentation clearly states that Jackson modules are applied to all ObjectMappers that including a Spring MVC annotation doesn't throw a warning or they don't get applied.

Comment: afaik they are only applied to `ObjectMapper`s defined by Spring and not your own explicitly configured ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to above comment by M. Deinum I have solved it. There was an @EnableWebMvc annotation on an imported class. Removing this solves the problem.